# Visual Studio Web API: How to change the routing path

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, routes

I am working on Web Api. By default, it uses the api/{controller}/{id} as a url. I am able to have it to route api/device/{controller}/{id} but this will affect to all Web API route to that path.

But I only want certain controller to be in api/device/{controller}/{id} and the rest will go to another path.

I saw something like RoutePrefix but it doesn't seem to work...

```
[RoutePrefix (api/data/abc)] where abc is the controller name.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the custom route mapping in WebApiConfig.cs file before default route map:
By adding this before, any requests which matches the custom route will be executed, else the other one.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "CustomRoute",
            routeTemplate: "api/device/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: But this still map if I typed in api/abc/3 but this should be under api/device/abc/3.  So if I typed api/abc/3, should be page not found.

Comment: can you come over to chat - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110209/karthik-simon

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize the routing with a *per controller* approach, then you have to use Attribute Routing instead of the standard convention-based routing.

Decorate your controllers with `RoutePrefix` attribute, and your actions with `Route` attribute in this way:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/device/mydevice")]
public class MyDeviceController : ApiController {

    [Route("{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id) {
        //DoWork
        //...
    }
}
```

And remember to enable attribute routing on the `HttpConfiguration` object:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

You may also remove `MapHttpRoute` method calls if you do not want to allow access to your actions in the standard convention-based way.

More on attribute routing on the [official documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).